# C# - why is my custom control not visible

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, user-controls, controls

I'm looking for some help on as to why my custom/user control is not visible.

code where I add my control:

```
ctlMapIcon mapIcon      = new ctlMapIcon();
mapIcon.Name            = "name";
mapIcon.LabelText       = "dummy map icon";
mapIcon.Parent          = picboxRegion1;
mapIcon.Width           = 130;
mapIcon.Height          = 70;
mapIcon.IconLocation    = new Point(100, 100);
this.tabRegion1.Controls.Add(mapIcon);
```

Code to build control:
public partial class ctlMapIcon : UserControl
    {
        private bool isAlarm;

```
    private Image iconAlarm;
    private Image iconOk;
    private Image iconInactive;

    string lblTextIconName;

    public bool SetAlarm
    {
        set
        {
            isAlarm = value;
            if (isAlarm)
            {
                picboxIcon.Image = iconAlarm;
            }
            else
            {
                picboxIcon.Image = iconOk;
            }
        }
        get 
        { 
            return isAlarm; 
        }
    }

    public bool SetInactive
    {
        set
        {
            if (value)
            {
                picboxIcon.Image = iconInactive;
            }
            else
            {
                picboxIcon.Image = iconOk;
            }
        }

    }

    public string LabelText
    {
        set
        {
            brdLblIconName.Text = lblTextIconName;
        }
        get
        {
            return lblTextIconName;
        }
    }

    public ctlMapIcon()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //set all elements of the control to transparent
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        this.BackColor              = Color.Transparent;
        picboxIcon.BackColor        = Color.Transparent;
        brdLblIconName.BackColor    = Color.Transparent;

        //set icon images
        iconAlarm       = Properties.Resources.mapicon_inalarm;
        iconOk          = Properties.Resources.mapicon_ok;
        iconInactive    = Properties.Resources.mapicon_ok;

        //set defaults
        picboxIcon.Image    = iconOk;
        picboxIcon.Width    = 40;
        picboxIcon.Height   = 40;
        brdLblIconName.Text = "site";
        this.Location       = new Point(5, 5);
        this.Height         = 70;
        this.Width          = 130;

    }

    public Point IconLocation
    {
        get { return this.Location; }
        set { this.Location = value; }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: sorry no, there is also a custom control that I've created. should I include that too?

Comment: A screenshot could be helpful. Is the `tabRegion1` control large enough? Is there relevant code in your custom control that could stop it from painting? Why do set `Parent` to `picboxRegion1` when you then add the control to `tabRegion1`?

Comment: @PaulAlexander The problem may be in the custom control code, or it may be somewhere else. What happens when you take the code you have in your question, and do the exact same thing but with a TextBox rather than your `ctlMapIcon` class? If you do the same thing with a standard control and the same problem happens (or *doesn't* happen), that's a clue about where the problem might be found. Like Rene, I'd like to know about `picboxRegion1` and `tabRegion1`,

Comment: Not related but there are naming convention. You should call your class `CtlMapIcon` with capital C :)

Comment: try tweaking X and Y coordinates

Comment: @RenéVogt is onto something with the question on `Parent`.  Setting `mapIcon.Parent` to `picboxRegion1` adds it to `picboxRegion1`'s `Controls` list.  When you later add `mapIcon` to `this.tabRegion1.Controls`, I'm not even sure *what* will happen, since you're trying to make it a child of `tabRegion1` when you've already made it a child of `picboxRegion1`.  You'd have to look at the reference source to see how .NET handles this, but I'd just recommend: don't do it.

Comment: @RenéVogt I set that as parent so that the windows form will handle transparency correctly.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I will try with a textbox

Comment: If I add a textbox, It appears but is partially hidden behind the picturebox already in the tab. It could be that my mapicon is also hidden behind......

Comment: I did mapIcon.BringToFront(); and it appeared!! Thanks for your help guys, I don't think I would have solved this by myself!